# Regression with country-wise deletion

Tags: r, loops, regression, logistic-regression

I'm trying to run a logit regression with country-wise deletion in R. Say I have a data frame with four variables over time: year, countryid (1-12), gdp, and population. I'd like to figure out a way to run 12 different regressions, each removing a single country, to see what the effect of pulling each out is. I've been trying to write a loop that drops the coefficients in a vector but haven't had any success.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please show some of your efforts.

Comment: Using `iris`, something like this: `lapply(levels(iris$Species),function(x) lm(Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width,data=iris[iris$Species!=x,]))`. You obtain different `data.frame`s with the level of the variable of interest removed and run a linear model (`lm`) from each. Guess you can adapt the idea to your actual data.

Comment: I've rolled back your edit that just said "Question has been deleted". Once your question has been answered it cannot be directly deleted as that would necessarily delete the answers other people have put time and effort into providing. Since you said Heroka's answer "worked perfectly", what you should do is upvote and accept their answer.

Comment: If you really want the question deleted, it would need to be Closed first. It doesn't seem like any of the close reasons apply, so getting the 5 needed close votes from high reputation users is unlikely...

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer that you will need to edit a little to work with the exact variables you have

```
data(mtcars)


y_var<-'mpg'
x_vars<-setdiff(names(mtcars),y_var)

for(i in x_vars){

  variables<-setdiff(x_vars,i)
  fm <- as.formula(paste(y_var, " ~", paste(variables, collapse = "+")))
  linear_model<-glm(fm, data = mtcars)
  assign(paste0('model_wout_',i),linear_model) #this will store your different linear models so you can call them with `summary(model.name)`

}
```

This is also a linear model - need to add "binomial" to make it logit...

Comment: OP wants to remove rows, not columns.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it.

Fake data:

```
set.seed(123)
nobs=500
dat <- data.frame(y = rbinom(nobs,1,0.5),
                  var1=rnorm(nobs),
                  var2=sample(LETTERS[1:12],nobs,T))
```

Vector of 'countries':

```
countries <- unique(dat$var2)
names(countries) <- countries
```

List of models (makes extracting things later easier):

```
models <- lapply(countries, function(x){
  fit <- glm(y~var1+var2, data=dat[dat$var2!=x,], family=binomial)
  fit
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
variables <- c("year", "countryid1", "id2", ..., "id12", "gdp", "population")

for (i in 2:13) {
variables.to.fit <- variables[-i]
}
```

Then you have to put your logit fit in this loop. In each loop. This will drop each id variable in each drop.